# ui is not defined with draggable

Tags: jquery

offset value but console tell me it is not defined :

```
ui is not defined
```

In my HTML the jquery script are included:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/templates/protostar/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/templates/protostar/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/templates/protostar/js/jclip.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/templates/protostar/js/cp.js"></script>
```

I don't understand...this is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready
    (
        function () {
            $('.mapban').parent().jclip(0, 0, 1060, 750);

            $('#mapplane').draggable({ containment: $('#containermy'),
            scroll: false,
            drag: function() {  
            console.log(ui.offset);
             },


            });

 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your drag handler method, you are using a variable called `ui` but is not declared anywhere in the scope of the function that is the reason for the error.

The [drag event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) handler receives 2 arguments, first is the event, second one is an `ui` object which contains some data specific to the widget event, you need to enhance the event handler method signature to accept those parameters as given below.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.mapban').parent().jclip(0, 0, 1060, 750);
    $('#mapplane').draggable({
        containment: $('#containermy'),
        scroll: false,
        drag: function (event, ui) { //here ui is the second parameter
            console.log(ui.offset);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add parameters `drag: function (event, ui) {`

See [**event-drag**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mapban').parent().jclip(0, 0, 1060, 750);
        $('#mapplane').draggable({
            containment: $('#containermy'),
            scroll: false,
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.offset);
            },
        });
    });
});
```